# Selecting a [long] part of text in evince

Tags: evince

I want to select a long part of text,say from starting of page 200 to end of page 400 in evice. How can I do this most quickly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no menu element or dialog that lets you do this in Evince, but you can use a combination of the mouse and the keyboard to do it.

1) Go to your starting point and left-click the mouse. If you drag down while keeping the mouse button pressed, you will start highlighting. You can also start highlighting by pressing the down arrow.

2) To select hundreds of pages, keep the mouse button pressed and press and hold the down arrow. You can move hundreds of pages in a few seconds.

3) Watch the table of contents on the left (if the doc has one). When you are near your destination, keep the mouse button pressed but let go of the down arrow.

*Warning: It may take several seconds for the display of the selection on the screen to catch up. Be sure to keep the mouse button down until you see your selection.*

You probably won't be exactly where you need to be, you can use the arrow keys to adjust the selection as long as you don't let go of the mouse button.